# google-map-react make the initial map cover the whole screen

Tags: google-maps, next.js, react-google-maps, react-google-maps-api

I am using @react-google-maps/api to use google map inside Next JS app.

Based on their documents, they mentioned that the parent HTML element could determine the size of the map.

My return function from my component looks like this:

```
return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
        height: "100vh",
        width: "100%",
      }}
    >
      <GoogleMap
        options={mapOptions}
        zoom={mapOption.zoom}
        center={mapCenter}
        mapTypeId={google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP}
        mapContainerStyle={{width: "300px",height: "300px"}}
        onLoad={() => console.log("Map Component Loaded...")}
      />
    </div>
  )
```

So basically I need to determine the width and height of the map and via parent, it would be overridden if I want to make it fill the entire screen. The problem is that the above return still shows the map with 300 to 300 px.
Does anyone have any solution so that the initial map fills the entire screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### MapContainerStyle is a child of your div container

It's because the `<GoogleMap />` attribute `mapContainerStyle` is also a seperate container and is only a child of the `<div>` container outside it, where you put the `style` attribute.

So although you set the `<div>` container with 100% width and height or 100vh/vw, if it's child component got a lower width and height, most especially because what you're using here is pixels, ofcourse it would show as only 300px in width and also in height.

### Here's an example:

[image: Sample 1]

```
return (
    <div
      style={{
        backgroundColor: "green",
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
        height: "500px",
        width: "500px"
      }}
    >
      <GoogleMap
        mapContainerStyle={{
          margin: "auto",
          width: "50%",
          height: "50%"
        }}
        center={center}
        zoom={3}
      ></GoogleMap>
    </div>
)
```

Notice that the `<div>` container having a green background and height/width of 500px, shows that it contains the `mapContainerStyle` provided here that I set the width and height to 50%.

So if you want to fill the 500px square `<div>` container, you should just set the height and width of `mapContainerStyle` to 100%. It would look like this:

[image: Sample 2]

```
return (
    <div
      style={{
        backgroundColor: "green",
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
        height: "500px",
        width: "500px"
      }}
    >
      <GoogleMap
        mapContainerStyle={{
          margin: "auto",
          width: "100%",
          height: "100%"
        }}
        center={center}
        zoom={3}
      ></GoogleMap>
    </div>
)
```

So to answer your question, you can just leave your `<div>` container without any styling, then setting the `mapContainerStyle` to 100% for it's width and height. Or you can set your `<div>` container as you have on your sample, depending on your use case. But here's the sample for both.

### Without `<div>` styling:

[image: Without div styling sample]

```
return (
    <div>
      <GoogleMap
        mapContainerStyle={{
          margin: "auto",
          width: "100%",
          height: "100%"
        }}
        center={center}
        zoom={3}
      />
    </div>
)
```

### With `<div>` styling:

[image: with div styling]

```
return (
    <div
      style={{
        height: "100vh",
        width: "100%"
      }}
    >
      <GoogleMap
        mapContainerStyle={{
          margin: "auto",
          width: "100%",
          height: "100%"
        }}
        center={center}
        zoom={3}
      ></GoogleMap>
    </div>
)
```

Hope this helps! Feel free to leave a comment if you need clarification or if I misunderstood your question somehow. But that's about it from me for now.

Comment: Thanks but in your first solution ( without div) when I put 100% for with and height of the mapContainerStyle, the map does not show. However, if I put height:100vh ( or by px) then it works.

Comment: Really? What you meant is without div styling right? Because removing the div would ofcourse not let the map show. That's weird because it worked for me. Let me test it out again. Will keep you updated on this one.

Comment: I used the following on mapContainerStyle :
  width: "100%",
  height: "100vh"

Comment: Or basically the below on your codes :
return (
    <div>
      <GoogleMap
        mapContainerStyle={{
          margin: "auto",
          width: "100%",
          height: "10vh"
        }}
        center={center}
        zoom={3}
      />
    </div>
)

Comment: I tried it just know and it still seems to work. here, check out this codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-google-maps-api-template-forked-8cpvgc

Comment: You are right. No idea why does not work on my side if I do not use 100vh for the height. The only thing that I could say I am using Next JS

Comment: Would 100vh be fine for your use case? or you need the 100%?

Comment: 100vh is ok but not 100%

Comment: You can just use 100vh then?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Yes